# Issue while connecting to sql hosted in docker from .net core api running in windows

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

This is my connection string in appsettings and appsettings.dev json file

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost,1433;Database=Cancer;User Id='sa';Password='dockersql';Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Encrypt=true;"
  }
```

I'm getting this error in sql log

```
2023-01-18 13:56:23.74 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
2023-01-18 13:56:23.74 Logon       Login failed for user '6fc2cfab8782\Guest'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 172.17.0.1]
```

I checked the appsettings and connectionstring conventions. I honestly don't know why it's using conatainername/domainname instead of the user id I'm mentioning.

The api is running in windows and in visual studio. Database is dockerized.

Comment: `Trusted_Connection` and `User id` + `Password` ?

Comment: You cannot have both `User Id` to specify an SQL account *and* `Trusted_Connection=true`, which tells it to use your Windows account. Removing `Trusted_Connection=true` should fix it (and then you probably need to remove the single quotes).

Comment: You *can't* pass windows credentials like they are a SQL Authentication login. It's one *or* the other.

Comment: There'd be a lot less questions like this if people took the time to read the documentation once in a while, [SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments. Removing `Trusted_Connection=true` resolved the issue.